# How to transpose this dataset in SAS?

Tags: sas

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want to get:

[image]

This is my code, which does not work:

```
proc transpose data = ratings_long out = ratings_wide prefix=Item;
    by ComID; 
    id Item;
    var Value;
run;
```

Comment: "does not work" how?? What output do you get? Why is that wrong?

Comment: Your output seems to be grouping by COMID and FISYEAR.  So include both in the BY statement.  You will probably need to sort first (or make a view that sorts).

Comment: Please do not post data as images per SO guidelines. For anyone who actually wanted to work with your data that would mean typing it out.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `FisYear` if you want it to be part of the process.

```
proc transpose data = ratings_long out = ratings_wide prefix=Item;
    by ComID FisYear; 
    id Item;
    var Value;
run;
```

Your display is not sorted so you might need to first call PROC SORT to sort the data by COMID FISYEAR.